# FireBase Real Time Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Database in an Android application, and everytime a user is singUp I store some values in the database for this purpose I am doing what follows:

```
@Override
public void writeObject(IUser object) {
    User usrReal = (User) object ; // this userReal's reference same with parameter
    User usrCopy = new User(usrReal); // copy of it
    String usrId = usrCopy.getUserId();

    databaseReference.child("usrId").setValue(usrCopy);
    //databaseReference = this.databaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(path) is defined beginning of the class
}
```

as you see in the child method if called "usrId" it create usrId directory and add all neccesary information in it. But I want to create directory for every user ,so I tried to pass usrId variable as a parameter. Howewer it doesn't work. When I debug the code debugger says that Local var usrId can not recognized.My question is How can I create nested structure in Firebase wrt. user's id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `userId` is the id generated by firebase authentication, then you can do:

```
String userId = user.getUid();
this.databaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
this.databaseReference.child(userId).child("name").setValue("peter");
```

Then you will have this structure:

```
Users
  userId 
    name : peter
  userId1
    name : john
```

Comment: I generate ids from android.os.Build.ID to detect the device that send request.In that case my variable cause a run time error.

Comment: Why not get the ids from firebase authentication or from the `push()` method

Comment: I have just started to use push() method. But it create different value every time ,so I should traverse all base to find correct user's identifier every time and I have to  get all data and search it on clients device.I wanted to reach data on server side.

Comment: in your code did you try this `String usrId = usrCopy.getUserId();

        databaseReference.child("usrId").setValue(userId);` `userId` instead of `userCopy`?

Comment: of course I tried that ,databaseReference.child("usrId") if we get "usr id" like this we can not write more than 1 object in that location. Because firebase overrite it.

Comment: yes if it is the same `id` always then it will be overwritten, that's why I said use firebase authentication id for every user, you can easily retrieve id and you don't need to traverse. Or you can do `child(userId).push()`

Comment: Ok . this time I understand you . Thanks very much .